# Create new JAXB Marshaller instance in static method... is it ThreadSafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, jaxb

I have implemented a util class with the following static method:

```
public static String objToXml(JAXBContext jaxbContext, ClassA obj) throws Exception{
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true );
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(obj, writer);
    return writer.toString();
}
```

My understanding is that JAXB Marshaller and StringWriter are both thread safe ... but I want to double confirm if I implement a static method like this.. and  have multiple threads calling objToXml method concurrently, would there be any potential issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you must create a new `Marshaller` each time around if you are planning to use them multi-threaded.

See [Unofficial JAXB Guide](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#other-miscellaneous-topics-performance-and-thread-safety)

> The JAXBContext class is thread safe, **but the Marshaller, Unmarshaller, and Validator** classes are **not thread safe**.